# Output sum of two numbers to console

Tags: c#, console

I am trying to get the sum of two numbers, but it is not displaying correctly. Here is the code:

```
int number1 = 1;
int number2 = 3;

Console.Write("The sum of " number1 "and" number2 "is" total ".");
```

Comment: Where are you declaring your variables, what is wrong, and I believe you need to use + to add your strings?

Comment: I declared the variable at the beginning of the program but I believe you are right...

Comment: The code you show doesn't even compile! And, somewhere you have to write `total = number 1 + number2;`

Comment: I know it doesn't compile that is why I am asking...and that is just a snippet...

Comment: Saying "it is not displaying correctly" is a rather poor description of a compiler error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
Console.Write("The sum of " + number1 + " and " + number2 + " is " + total +".");
```

You need the `+` operator to concatenate string together.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
Console.Write("The sum of {0} and {1} is {2}.", number1, number2, total);
```

Comment: Given that OP doesnt actually have a `var total` and this is such a simple question, you might want to add the numbers for him.

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey - samesies :P